# Как проверить на существование картинки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я циклом создаю div'ы и записывая в их data-id - src картинок, как проверить существуют ли картинки по таким src в папке?

Comment: скорее всего через ajax. Если получаете код 404, значит картинки нету

Comment: Как через ajax?

Comment: @MrMess не дубликат, другая проблема, вроде бы.

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("something");

Array.from(divs, div => {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = div.dataset.id;
  img.onload = () => console.log("I'm alive!");
  img.onerror = () => console.log("Not found :(");
});
```

```html
<div data-id="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_960_720.jpg" class="something"></div>
<div data-id="sample.com/wqfqwf.png" class="something"></div>
```

Comment: Присутствует только самая первая картинка, почему переменная isExist = undef? https://jsfiddle.net/vz139ubo/

Comment: потому что операция img.onload/onerror асинхронная, а код выполняется последовательно.

Comment: Как пофиксить?)

Comment: Примерно так - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788934/how-to-turn-this-callback-into-a-promise-using-async-await.

Answer (score 0):

Создаёшь картинку, загружаешь. Если есть - onload, нет - onerror:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://site.ru/img.png';
img.onload = function(){alert('картинка существует')};
img.onerror = function(){alert('картинка не существует')};
```

Или такой вариант для логики отображения/скрытия:

```
<img src = "1.jpg" onerror = "this.style.display = 'none'">
```

Comment: Присутствует только самая первая картинка, почему переменная isExist = undef? https://jsfiddle.net/vz139ubo/